# How do I convert to object different pattern in java

Tags: java

I have a set of data about book.

I have to convert the data to object. Line(book, chapter, verse, content)

The structure is
Book Chapter:Verse[tab]Content[Enter]

Example
deuteronomy 7:7 the lord did not set his love upon you, nor choose you, because ye were more in number than any people; for ye were the fewest of all people:

1 samuel 17:6   and he had greaves of brass upon his legs, and a target of brass between his shoulders.

As the book structure is different. 
`1 samuel` and `deuteronomy`
`1 samuel` consist a space. how do i convert these data to object in java

I have already divide into two part
`StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString().toLowerCase(),"\t");`
I think I should use `regex` to split them. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at regular expressions. If the content doesn't contain any new line characters (i.e. `\n` which I assume is what you mean by `[Enter]`) you can try the following expression:

`(.*?) (\d+):(\d+)\t([^\n]+)`

Break down of the expression:

- `(.*?)`  matches anything but as little as possible and collects it into group 1. The match ends with a space which is not selected - this is the book
- `(\d+)` matches any sequence with at least 1 digit and captures it into a group. So `(\d+):(\d+)` captures chapter and verse into groups 2 and 3.
- `\t([^\n]+)` matches a tab followed by a sequence of at least 1 non-new line character which is captured into group 4. This is the content.

For working with regex like this, have a look at the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Then I use Matcher.find and Matcher.group() to set different variable?

Comment: @anonymous exactly. Use `Matcher.find()` to get the next match and then `group(1)` to `group(4)` to get the individual sub groups. Just note that your string needs proper formatting, i.e. the regex above would expect each text is on its own line and there are no other line breaks in the content.